# Confused about this and bind(this) of react writing es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
class UserList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.something => (
               console.log('something')
            )
    }

    createListItem(){
        return this.props.users.map(user => 
            <li key={user.id}>{user.first} {user.last}</li>)
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <ul>
                {this.createListItem()}
            </ul>
            <button onClick={this.something}>trigger something</button>
        )
    }
}
```

If I remove `<button>` and `this.something` function within the constructor the code will work. What's wrong with below code? actually I don't need the constructor function but I want to investigate when to use `bind(this)` and when not to using ES6 to write React.

Comment: I think question heading may not address your actual question. Kindly update your question heading

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually assigning a valid function expression, so let's start with that.

First, if you're not accepting any arguments, the correct syntax for arrow functions is:

```
() => { console.log('something'); }
```

Ok, now that that's sorted, you need to actually assign it using the assignment operator:

```
this.something = () => { console.log('something'); }
```

Great, that should now make the constructor work. Let's look at where you're actually using the function from:

```
<button onClick={this.something}>trigger something</button>
```

So, historically, prior to ES2015, indeed something like this would mean that the callback would not be bound to the instance, unless you used the expression `this.something.bind(this)` or assigned it in the construtor like you're trying to do.

But if you want to use arrow functions, what they're really convenient for is to write anonymous functions, so you could actually do something like this straight up for simple use cases:

```
<button onClick={() => this.foo()}>trigger something</button>
```

If not, I'd recommend that you really don't use anonymous functions in the constructor or as an expression for callbacks and instead write a method for it and use [the new `::` bind operator](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-function-bind/) with Babel, specifically the self auto binding behavior.

Then you'll end up with something like this:

```
class UserList extends Component {
  createListItem () {
    return this.props.users.map(user => (
      <li key={user.id}>{user.first} {user.last}</li>
    ))
  }

  something () {
    this.setState({foo: 'bar'})
    console.log('something')
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <ul>{this.createListItem()}</ul>
      <button onClick={::this.something}>trigger something</button>
    )
  }
}
```

This is both neat and can save you from writing *useless* constructors.

Comment: new :: is available in which version es2015 - stage 0 or state 1?

Comment: Can you please explain why? 
"I'd recommend that you really don't use anonymous functions in the constructor or as an expression for callbacks "

Comment: @WitVault I think it hurts the legibility of `render()` if you put in lots of non-trivial anonymous functions. If you find yourself extracting them and assigning them to variables at the top, then definitely promote them to instance methods. I'd definitely avoid writing them in the constructor, especially when you can use self auto binding.

Comment: @WitVault at the time of writing, it is a [Stage-0 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/stage-0-proposals.md)